# Regex for navigation path

Tags: regex

How can i match navigation childs (only index.php) included also first level after child (see last two examples).

administration/peoples/index.php  (**match**)

administration/peoples/roles.php (no match)

administration/analytics/index.php (**match**)

administration/publications/index.php (**match**)

administration/publications/set.php (no match)

administration/publications/test/index.php (**match !important**)

administration/publications/test/subtest/index.php (**no match !important**)

THX

Comment: You're question doesn't make very much sense.  What program language are you looking to match with?

Comment: "included also first level after child" <-- explain please

Comment: mysql ^administration+(.+\/index[^/]+)$ but last one its also matched!!!!

Comment: i nead to match all index.php pages in "publications" folder and also in eveery publications subfolder (in this case test) but not in any other subfolders from test (in this examples subtest/index.php) Thank You

Answer (score 1):

One way (perl flavour). As I understand, first folder must be 'administration', last file must be 'index.php' and must be one or two subfolders between them.

```
m|^(?i:administration)/(?:[^/]+/){1,2}(?i:index\.php)\s*$|
```

Explanation:

```
m|...|                  # Regex expresion, pipe is separator to avoid escape slashes inside regex.
^                       # (zero-width) Begin of line.
(?i:administration)/        # Literal string 'administration/' ignoring case.
(?:[^/]+/){1,2}         # Any characters plus a slash one or two times.
(?i:index\.php)             # Literal string 'index.php' ignoring case.
\s*                     # Posible space characters after string, maybe zero.
$                       # (zero-width) End of line.
```

Comment: Why this pattern is supported in regex editor but not in mysql query?

Comment: @adoweb: I don't understand what `mysql query` means. Perhaps flavour is different?

Answer (score 0):

Use string operations instead:

- if the input doesn't start with `administration/`, no match, skip;
- if the input doesn't end with `/index.php`, no match, skip;
- if the input contains `/test/`, not important.

No need for regexes here!

Answer (score -1):

`#^administration/(.*?)index.php$#`

Comment: Nope... Consider `administration/foobarindex.php`

Comment: Maybe, but not excluded by the OP explicitly, so I won't mod :)